# Compare two strings encrypted by openssl

Tags: openssl, comparison

Is it possible to compare two strings that were encrypted by the same OpenSSL RSA public key without any need to decrypt them first using the private key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenSSL: Same rsa keys, different encrypts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329526/openssl-same-rsa-keys-different-encrypts)

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL would be the library or application you use to do the encryption.

The encryption implementation or strategy would determine if the two encrypted strings would be comparable.

Simple encryption methods would be comparable, whereas more complex and secure encryption methods (like RSA) use padding and would encrypt the same string with different resulting encryption strings.

Comment: Could you suggest another way that uses a private and public key which is comparable, please?

Comment: In which context do you want to use it ? A custom application ? You can try and use block encryption without padding. Like AES without padding.
Check out this site for online encrypting, it lets you specify a key so someone else with the key can decrypt again.

Comment: Yes, kind of! I want to store sensitive data in the server. But the have to be encrypted for security reasons but only be compared while they are encrypted. And in some certain I want the data be recoverable by a key that is not stored in the server.

Comment: I take it this is just so the data is not readable by humans ?
Otherwise, a stronger encryption method might be better. A bit of extra work, but worth it.

All major languages have encryption libraries built in, just do a search for some examples of the language your using. Databases can actually do that too.