# RSA_public_encrypt giving garbage output in output buffer

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

Below is my updated code. which works fine for encrypting but fails for decryption.
i don't want padding and hence i am using no padding which also ensures that the output of encryption will be same for each run.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/opensslconf.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rc4.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
        //modulus in format char hex;
        char key[] = "dsfasdfsdfc58553eaa0e204e72b3e64d304c87192507926cb45062ee21d0ebef1bbf79d880d1f3e03f95b2264qwerewrwerw5b577226f9a9212b961209c6b85e9ed72adee43c387c8a9b7c1d74d018a03c498b09a84sadfsdfsdfsdfsadfasf2342f133d7";

        RSA * pubkey = RSA_new();

        BIGNUM * modul = NULL;
        BIGNUM * expon = NULL;

        //if(modul==NULL || expon==NULL || pubkey==NULL)
        //      printf("modul or expon or rsa could not be created\n");


        int len=BN_hex2bn(&modul, (const char *) key);

        printf("modul len = %d \n",len);
        printf("expon len =%d \n",BN_hex2bn(&expon, (const char *)"11"));

        printf("N KEY: [%s]\n",BN_bn2hex(modul));
        printf("E KEY: [%s]\n",BN_bn2hex(expon));

        pubkey->n = modul;
        pubkey->e = expon;
        pubkey->iqmp = NULL;
        pubkey->d = NULL;
        pubkey->p = NULL;
        pubkey->q = NULL;
        pubkey->dmp1=NULL;
        pubkey->dmq1=NULL;

        int size=RSA_size(pubkey);
        int size1;
        char text[size];
        char *encryptedText=(char*)malloc(size);
        char *decryptedText=(char*)malloc(size);
        int ret;
        char buf[100];

        memset(encryptedText,'\0',sizeof(encryptedText));

        strcpy(text,"4200000000000000|01|2012|121|V|122002-1111111111-NA");

        printf("size = [%d] strlen(text) = [%d] destText = [%s]\n",size,strlen(text),encryptedText);

//      srand(time(NULL));      //seeding random number generator

        if((size1=RSA_public_encrypt(size,(const unsigned char *)text,(unsigned char *)encryptedText,pubkey,RSA_NO_PADDING))<0)
        {
                printf("ERRO encrypt\n");
                printf("errno : [%d]\n",errno);
                ERR_error_string(errno, buf);
                printf("size1 =%d errno %d\n",size1,errno);
                printf("ERR STR [%s]\n",buf);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("SUCCESSFULLY encrypted\n");
                printf("bytes converted [%d]\n",size1);
                printf("ENC:: size [%d] string [%s]\n",strlen(encryptedText),encryptedText);
        }
 memset(decryptedText,'\0',sizeof(decryptedText));

        //      printf("size = [%d] encryptedText = [%s] decryptedText = [%s]\n",size,encryptedText,decryptedText);

                if((size=RSA_private_decrypt(size1,(unsigned char *)encryptedText,(unsigned char *)decryptedText,pubkey,RSA_NO_PADDING))<0)
                {
                printf("ERRO encrypt\n");
                printf("errno : [%d]\n",errno);
                ERR_error_string(errno, buf);
                printf("ERR STR [%s]\n",buf);
                }
                else
                {
                printf("SUCCESSFULLY decrypted\n");
                printf("bytes converted [%d]\n",size1);
                printf("DCRYPTED:: [%s]\n",decryptedText);
                }

        //      BN_free(expon);
        //      BN_free(modul);
        //      if(pubkey)

        free(encryptedText);
        free(decryptedText);
        RSA_free(pubkey);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of 'size', and what is the value of 'strlen(text)'?

Comment: You need to initialize private key parameters. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

1> What is the value of 'size' which you have used in

```
char text[size];  
char encryptedText[size];`
```

2> It seems like you are trying to get value of size by
`int size = RSA_size(pubkey);` 
which appearently is rsa public key size.

You Cannot define array without specifying size of it. In your case you want to give size to your array at runtime.Thats not possible because `Static arrays` are allocated memory at compile time and the memory is allocated on the stack. So if you want to allocate memory at run time use `dynamic array`.

3> `RSA_public_encrypt` function takes first argument as `length of data to be encrypted`. so it will be better to use `strlen(text)` (as suggested by alk) instead of hardcoding it.

4> `RSA_public_encrypt` in your program is correctly encrypting the data. Problem is while printing.You are asking printf to print a string via the %s. so it prints the contents of the string till it encounters `'\0'` in encrypted buffer.

**UPDATE**
If **RSA_NO_PADDING** is used then input must have the same size as the modulus.
That means a 1024-bit RSA key works on 1024 bits of input and returns 1024 bits of output. If your input is not the same size as the key, you must use padding to make it so. If you do not use padding, than the RSA algorithm cannot be executed.
In terms of the **OpenSSL** API, the buffer that is passed in need to be 128 bytes.

Comment: if((size1=RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(text),(const unsigned char *)text,(unsigned char *)encryptedText,pubkey,RSA_NO_PADDING))<0) ,this is my new version of code, now i have used strlen(text) to be encrypted and also i am dynamically allocating the to buffer i.e. encryptedText here, but still function is returning -1 but errno is 0, i wonder how is it possible ,and i can't change the method of generating my public key, if there is something wrong in the way please mention .. thanks guys

Comment: i have used padding , now function returns size of encrypted data which is different each time and output buffer contains value each time different. please bother..

Comment: Nitish bro, Actual confusion is in Padding what you are using. Consider if you are using RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING then your plaintext will be encoded to  OAEP encoding form making it exact size of rsa modulus. SO your plain text will be encoded and then encrypted. and while decrypting it is decrypted first then decoded to your plaintext form.So nothing wrong with your program. Better try Decrypting it you will get exact data which you encrypted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389211/openssl-rsa-public-encrypt-strange-behavior

Comment: i have checked the link u mentioned above. and i understood the concept of padding but now my problem is the rsa_private_dercypt which causes segmentation fault and when i executed the program through gdb it mention : current function bounds could not found. i tried the same program on another machine but the problem persists there too.

Comment: There can be many reason for segmentation fault like dangling pointer, memory access violation.Its difficult to say without looking at your code.Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, for RSA_private_decrypt(), you need the private key. But I don't see you have any private key with you. (i.e. `rsa-> d` (private exponent) must be known to you)

Comment: ok, but my problem persists with no padding to i am getting new a garbage value each time.

Comment: Well, you can't use strlen to get length of a binary data, and pritntf to print them. Better to get the length from the RSA_public_encrypt function and print the hex values inside a for loop.
`for(i = 0; i<size1; i++) printf("%02x ", encryptedText[i]);`

Comment: @NitishKamal bgamlath is correct. when you use RSA_private_decrypt this function looks for privateExponent  i.e d of your key. and in your program you are using public key for both encrypt and decrypt operation. this got nothing to do with padding. and its not garbage data.that data itself is encrypted data/cipher. It will be better if go through some basic tutorials.It seems you need some foundation  for public key cryptography.

Comment: thanks Nimish Salve and bgamlath for clearifying me. actually i am converting a java code to corresponding c code. in java version , i get same output every time . and there the ouput i got is in a byte array and i convert that in hexadecimal, here in c version i use to do same and each time even after converting the output to hexadecimal i got different output.

Comment: And you are getting random values because of this. 
When you declare the char text[size], it has garbage values.
When you use strcpy to fill it, only part of it get's filled.. rest is garbage. First clear the text array and then fill it.
And also, in `memset(encryptedText,'\0',sizeof(encryptedText));`, sizeof(encryptedText) give you the size of the pointer variable, 4 or 8 depending on system you are in. It is because it is allocated dynamically. Use `memset(encryptedText,'\0', size);` instead.

Comment: @NitishKamal: You have to be very careful when porting any other highlevel code to C. Specially memory allocating and initializing. I too had a lot of trouble when I first started with openssl.

Comment: thanks bgamlath, it worked and i am getting same output each time... thanks a lot for ur valuable time and effort,, thanks @Nimish Salve too.

Comment: anybody knows what minimum size of modulus the function rsa_public_encrypt accepts when used as a part of rsa key?

Comment: I don't think there is any restriction on that. The only restriction is regarding the length of the data you want to encrypt.

See the description in https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html

Comment: i used the modulus of size less than 256 bytes and it gives error no 0 but function returns -1

Comment: What was the length of the text you were trying to encrypt?

Comment: There might be some other issue with it. RSA_public_encrypt can encrypt small number of bytes and can be used with smaller key sizes than 256.

Answer (score 0):

1st issue I see is that in line

```
      if ((size1 = RSA_public_encrypt(
          size - 42,
          (const unsigned char *) text,
          (unsigned char *) encryptedText,
          pubkey,
          RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) < 0)
```

this

```
size - 42
```

should be

```
strlen(text)
```

---

From `man RSA_public_encrypt` (italics by me):

> int RSA_public_encrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from,
>              unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
>
> [...]
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> RSA_public_encrypt() encrypts the *flen bytes at from* (usually a session key) using the public key rsa and stores the ciphertext in to. to must point to RSA_size(rsa) bytes of memory.

Comment: @Nimish, my friend i have used padding now it is working but output is still garbage and each time different.